# Getting undefined value in jQuery select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get a value from select HTML in order to copare with Integer values and take an action or another. The problem is that I am always getting undefined value from select and then, I can not compare undefined with Integer, thanks.

**Code:**

```
var toRet
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#id_event_type').on('change', function() {
    toRet = $('#id_event_type :selected').val(); //:selected is not necesary I think
    alert($(toRet).val());//returns undefined

   });
});
if (toRet == 2){
    var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/stati/img/accidente.png',eventSize, eventOffset);
}
if (toRet == 0){
    var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/obrasMarker.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
}
if (toRet == 1){
   var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/alertMarker.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
}
if (toRet == ""){
   var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/alertMarker.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
}
eventMarkerslayer.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(eventPosition, eventIcon));
```

**Code updated:**

```
toRet = null;
//var selector = document.getElementById("id_event_type")
//var valorSeleccionado = selector.options[selector.selectedIndex].value;
$(document).ready(function(){           
  slc = $('#id_event_type');

  slc.on('change', function(){

    toRet = parseInt(slc.find(":selected").val(), 10);//here is ok!

   });
    //from here toRet is null                       
   if (toRet == 2){
     var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/accidente.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
   }
  if (toRet == 0){
    var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/obrasMarker.png',   eventSize, eventOffset);
  }
  if (toRet == 1){
    var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/atascoMarker.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
  }

  eventMarkerslayer.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(eventPosition,   eventIcon));
  eventMarkerslayer.setVisibility(false);
  $( "#visibilityEvents" ).change(function() {
      if ($('#visibilityEvents').is(":checked")) {
          eventMarkerslayer.setVisibility(true);
      } else {
          eventMarkerslayer.setVisibility(false);
      }
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="id_event_type" name="event_type" required="">
  <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
  <option value="0">Obras en la carretera</option>
  <option value="1">Congestion del trafico</option>
  <option value="2">Accidente</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var slc = $('#id_event_type');
  
  var value;
  
  slc.on('change', function(){
  value  = slc.find(":selected").val();
  alert(value);
  })
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id_event_type" name="event_type" required="">
  <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
  <option value="0">Obras en la carretera</option>
  <option value="1">Congestion del trafico</option>
  <option value="2">Accidente</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Suren, thanks, it works but now the problem is that outside of the jQuery function the var value does not exist, and if I create the variable before the function, after this one, the value becomes undefined, I am java script beginner and I am not able to understand this fact, thanks

Comment: @Andoni why you want to declare value outside of the function ?. It is a local variable.

Comment: I need to compare the var value outside of on change jquery function, if not, My icon picture will change every and only change in the select, I am trying to do that

Comment: outside of the function declare `var value`; and inside use `value = ..`.But for the first time value may be undefined

Comment: It does not work, after the function, value var is still containing the same value when it was created, have I to have in account the asynchronous fact? thanks Suren

Comment: @Andoni see my code.I have added it outside of the function.Check you code

Comment: Suren, I need to get the value of value var outside of jQuery function, there is the problem, inside works well, but if I put my condicional sentences inside too, it does not work correctly

Comment: @Andoni outside of which function ?

Comment: ourside of ready function. I have read that in javascrip there ara scopes, variables outside a function cannot be called inside a function

Comment: @Andoni Why? Put all your code in the `document.ready`. It is the main function of your js

Comment: @Andoni it will work. but put the `var` before `toRet`. But I suggest you to put all code into `ready()`

Comment: I continue with null after on change function ;(

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#id_event_type').on('change', function() {
    toRet = $('#id_event_type option:selected').val(); //getting val() here of selected option
    alert(toRet);//no neet to get .val() here

   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id_event_type" name="event_type" required="">
  <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
  <option value="0">Obras en la carretera</option>
  <option value="1">Congestion del trafico</option>
  <option value="2">Accidente</option>
</select>
```

Getting `.val()` of already value will really produce undefined

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple `val()` calls which are causing the issue. Also you don't need the `:selected` part of your selector:

```
var toRet
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#id_event_type').on('change', function() {
     toRet = $(this).val();// get the value of the select
     alert(toRet);
   });
});
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/rdtzy5af)

Since you want to compare the value as an integer, you can parse the string by using `parseInt()` like so (otherwise the value will be returned as a string):

```
toRet = parseInt( $(this).val(),10 );
```

[Working example with `parseInt()`](https://jsfiddle.net/gcxv3fkx/1/)

Comment: Thanks, its really usefull

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#id_event_type').on('change', function() {
        toRet = $('#id_event_type :selected').val();
        alert(toRet);

       });
    });
```

Comment: whith alert(toRet) I am getting blank value, maybe select does not change the selector and it sends the default blank? thanks

Comment: try this var toRet = $(this).val(); alert(toRet) @Andoni

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to again use the selector with

> $(toRet).val()

toret is solely referencing the value this time. Try the below

```
$('#id_event_type').on('change', function() {
    toRet = $('#id_event_type :selected').val(); //:selected is not necesary 
    alert(toRet);//return value

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code :
Try like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var toRet, eventIcon;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#id_event_type').on('change', function() {
      toRet = $('#id_event_type').val();
      if (toRet == 2){
            var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/stati/img/accidente.png',eventSize, eventOffset);
        }
        if (toRet == 0){
            var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/obrasMarker.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
        }
        if (toRet == 1){
           var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/alertMarker.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
        }
        if (toRet == ""){
           var eventIcon = new OpenLayers.Icon('/static/img/alertMarker.png', eventSize, eventOffset);
        }
      });
});
</script>
<body>
<select id="id_event_type" name="event_type" required="">
  <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
  <option value="0">Obras en la carretera</option>
  <option value="1">Congestion del trafico</option>
  <option value="2">Accidente</option>
</select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the **selected value** *by* **select field Name** instead of ID as below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#submit" ).click(function() {
     alert($("select[name=id_event_type]").val());
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="id_event_type" name="id_event_type" required="">
  <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
  <option value="0">Obras en la carretera</option>
  <option value="1">Congestion del trafico</option>
  <option value="2">Accidente</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
```